# Module#__temp__ in perftools.rb output

Tags: ruby, google-perftools

While profiling some of our Ruby code perftools.rb shows the following output:

```
Total: 291 samples                                                                                                
     110  37.8%  37.8%      112  38.5% #<Module:0x007ff364e2bfd0>#__temp__
     19   6.5%   44.3%       19   6.5% BigDecimal#div                                                             
     18   6.2%   50.5%      171  58.8% BinSearch::Methods#_bin_search
     15   5.2%   55.7%       15   5.2% BigDecimal#add
```

So, most of the time is spent in a method designated as `#<Module:0x007ff364e2bfd0>#__temp__`. How do I get more information on where this is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, that's probably where it's coming from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/ClassMethods.html#method-i-define_method_attribute

I'm still not sure why it shows up, though.  It looks like that method should exist for only a very short time.